# Issue with Windows Batch Script to change Icon for empty folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I've a small problem with an windows batch script.
In the script I search for empty folder and when the script find one, it will copy `desktop.ini` in it. My problem is when `robocopy` set the attribute, the folder will get also this attribute.

```
@echo=off

for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do ( dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || robocopy  "C:\Users\user2\Desktop\test Projekt" "%%~fA" /a+:SH "desktop.ini"

)
```

Comment: Use the `attrib` command to set the attributes of a file instead of using `robocopy`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this one line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) will achieve your intended task:

```sh
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "%~1" /A:D /B /S 2^>NUL') Do @For /F %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%G" : /HILQ 2^>NUL') Do @If %%H Equ 0 %SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe "%UserProfile%\Desktop\test Projekt" "%%G" "desktop.ini" /A+:SH 1>NUL
```

It uses a `for /f` loop with `dir`, instead of a `for /d /r` loop, to identify every directory, instead of non hidden ones. Then it uses `xcopy.exe` in another `for /f` loop, instead of `dir`, and `findstr.exe`, then used `if` instead of the and the conditional `||`, to pass only those without files to the `robocopy.exe` command line. The `robocopy` command should copy your `desktop.ini` files to those fileless directories as needed, changing the copied files attributes to `system` and `hidden`, as required.